# How to use onsubmit for form validation, when submit is nested within internal div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to validate a form, by using a validation function, using JS.
When I try to divide the form by using div elements, it doesn't call the validation function anymore.

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();"  method="post" action="form-handler.html">
    <div>
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="Jhon">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="submit">Submit</label>
        <input id="submit" type="Submit" value="send">
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    function validateForm(form) {
        //validation failed if first-name input is empty
        if(form.firstName.value == "")
        {
            alert("Error: Input is empty!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try `onsubmit="return validateForm(this);"`  You're not passing the form into your function

Comment: Also note that the `for` attribute in `<label />` should refer to an `id` of an `<input />` and will not work on the name. You can test the difference by clicking on your label and see whether your input is focused after that.

Comment: @Webber `label` can never be written as `<label />` and really, in 2019, there's no use for self-terminating tags even where they are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing up the form contents with `div` has no bearing on whether you can invoke a validation function. **The problem is that you aren't referring to the element that you want to validate correctly.** Your function expects an argument, which you called `form`, but your code to invoke the function doesn't pass any arguments, so inside your function, `form` is `undefined` and therefore you aren't locating the text field you want to validate.

Instead, just reference the element(s) you wish to test:

```html
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();"  method="post" action="form-handler.html">
    <div>
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="Jhon">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="submit">Submit</label>
        <input id="submit" type="Submit" value="send">
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    function validateForm(evt) {
        // Reference the field(s) to validate properly:
        if(document.querySelector("[name='firstName']").value == ""){
            alert("Error: Input is empty!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Now, having said that, don't use inline HTML event attributes, like `onsubmit` in the first place. That technique is 25+ years old and won't die the death it deserves because of how often people just copy it without understanding [why it shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991). Instead, follow modern standards and separate all your JavaScript from your HTML. Also, your first `label` is not set up correctly. The `for` attribute value must match the `id` of the element that the label is "for".

```html
<form id="myForm"  method="post" action="form-handler.html">
    <div>
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" placeholder="Jhon">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="submit">Submit</label>
        <input id="submit" type="Submit" value="send">
    </div>
</form>

<script>

  // Get a reference to the form and set up a submit event handler
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", validate);
  
  // The argument is automatically passed and represents
  // the event itself
  function validate(evt) {
        //validation failed if first-name input is empty
        
        // Properly reference the element(s) you wish to test
        if(document.querySelector("[name='firstName']").value == ""){
            alert("Error: Input is empty!");
            
            // Tell the event not to proceed.
            evt.preventDefault(); 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: By the way, using `querySelector` in a form validator also introduces spaghetti code and fails to separate concerns, as it makes the JS dependent on the markup.

Comment: @WillardSolutions Having JS dependent on markup is not what determines if you are separating your concerns. And, querySelector requires a valid CSS selector to work - - there's no way around that. You confuse reference with combine.

Comment: You can't test JS that depends on markup, Just pass the form object into the function

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Change

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();"  method="post" action="form-handler.html">
```

Into

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)" method="post" action="form-handler">
```

To provide the form as an argument to your `validateForm` function.

**Option 2**

Change

```
 <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
<input name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="Jhon">
```

into

```
<label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
<input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" placeholder="Jhon">
```

To fix your form and make the input easily selectable in javascript.

Then:

```
function validateForm(form) {
  var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName')

  if (firstName.value == "") {
    alert("Error: Input is empty!");

    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Then your actual code must be different from your opening post, because this should work. Could you make a runnable code example that shows what doesn't work?